# Translations by a basis vector in a periodic potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

In the case of a periodic potential with translational invariance $ V(x+L) = V(x) $, why do we assume that the the translation operator , when acting on an energy eigenstate , makes the state pick up a phase instead of it remaining completely unchanged? That is,
$$ T_L\psi(x) = e^{i\phi}\psi(x) $$

An obvious response to this is that the probability amplitude shouldn't change on a translation ( otherwise the translational symmetry breaks down) , i.e $P(x) = P(x+L) $ and hence the maximum a wavefunction can do is pick up a phase. But this condition is also satisfied by the wavefunction not changing at all i.e $\psi(x+L) = \psi(x) $.

I understand that the differect eigenvalues of the translation operator correspond to different values of the wavevector $k$ , indicating how the phase of the wavefunction changes when we move spatially. But if the lattice is periodic, shouldn't the wave function be exactly the same (without any change is phase as well) in all the unit cells at the equivalents points (say the center) within those cells?

Is it just done to ensure the we remain as general as possible and make the least number of assumptions?

Comment: Yep pretty much.  This is Bloch's theorem, and the phase difference is important and not always just 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to understand is the Hilbert space we're working in.  We take $\mathcal H= L^2([-\frac{NL}{2},\frac{NL}{2}])$ (corresponding to $N$ atoms with equal spacing $L$ between them) with periodic boundary conditions (called Born-von Karman conditions).  Therefore, for any element of the Hilbert space $\Psi$ we must have that $\Psi(NL/2) = \Psi(-NL/2)$.

Next, the fact that $[H,T_L]=0$ means that we can find an energy eigenbasis $\{\psi_n\}$ which is also an eigenbasis for $T_L$.  You are asking why we don't assume that $T_L \psi_n = \psi_n$ for each one of these.

The answer is that any wavefunction $\Psi\in \mathcal H$ can be expanded as $\Psi = \sum_n c_n \psi_n$.  The action of $T_L$ on $\Psi$ is then

$$T_L (\Psi) = \sum_n c_n T_L(\psi_n) = \sum_n c_n \psi_n = \Psi $$

which implies that every possible wavefunction (not just energy eigenstates!) is lattice translation-invariant, which would mean that $T_L$ is simply the identity operator on $\mathcal H$.

This is obviously not the case.  An arbitrary element of $\mathcal H$ has no symmetry requirements whatsoever (it could be a Gaussian wavepacket located at the origin, for example).  Since $T_L$ is not the identity operator on the whole space, it cannot be the identity operator on the chosen basis $\{\psi_n\}$, which means that in general, $T_L \psi_n = \lambda \psi_n$ with $\lambda \neq 1$.

Though not the identity operator, $T_L$ *is* unitary, as $\langle T_L \psi, T_L \phi\rangle = \langle \psi,\phi\rangle$.  This implies in particular that $|\lambda|^2 = 1$, and therefore that $\lambda = e^{i\phi_n(x)}$ for some real-valued function $\phi_n(x)$.  This is the general idea behind Bloch's theorem.

---

Bloch's theorem goes on to show that any energy eigenfunction $\psi_n(x)$ can be written as $\psi_n(x) = e^{ikx}u_n(x)$ where $u_n$ is periodic with period $L$, and $k = -\frac{\pi}{L} + m\frac{2\pi}{NL}$ for integer $m$ between $0$ and $N-1$.  That is, $k\in [-\pi/L,\pi/L]$ in steps of $\frac{2\pi}{NL}$. We call these states Bloch waves.

From a comment,

> Is there any physical interpretation to the phase $\phi$?

Yes, absolutely.  $\hbar k$ is called the [*crystal momentum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_momentum) of the state.  It's not quite the same as normal momentum, but it's similar in many ways.  Crystal momentum is quite frequently conserved during interactions and collision, making it a very useful physical quantity.  One can also find the group velocity of localized wavepackets via

$$\mathbf v = \frac{1}{m} \nabla_{\mathbf k} E_n(k)$$

where $E_n(k)$ is the energy of the eigenstate $\psi_n = e^{ikx}u_n(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's assume we know nothing about $\psi(x)$. As far as we know $T_L\psi(x)=\psi(x+L)$ is just a shifted version of $\psi(x)$. What we do know is that $T_L$ commutes with the Hamiltonian (since it commutes with the kinetic energy operator and also with $V(x)$). So $[H,T_L]\psi(x)=0$. When two operators commute we know that they can form a [simultaneous eigenbasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_set_of_commuting_observables). That is, we can find eigenfunctions that are both eigenfunctions of $H$ and $T_L$. We can find $\psi_n(x)$ such that
\begin{align}
H\psi_n(x)&=E\psi_n(x)\\
T_L\psi_n(x)&=\lambda\psi_n(x)
\end{align}
This gives us $\psi_n(x+L)=\lambda\psi_n(x)$. Now we have to make sure this state is still normalised:
\begin{align}\int \mathrm{d}x\,|\psi(x+L)|^2&=\int \mathrm{d}x\,|\lambda\psi(x)|^2\\
&=|\lambda|^2\int \mathrm{d}x\,|\psi(x)|^2\\
&=|\lambda|^2=1
\end{align}
So we can conclude that $\lambda=e^{i\phi}$. If we restricted $\lambda$ to be 1 we would be missing out on all the Bloch waves.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "We would be missing out on all the Block Waves"? I understand the mathematical route you presented to conclude that $\lambda$ is a phase. Is there any physical interpretation to the phase $\phi$? As in why isn't the wave function exactly equal to its translated version ( the latter part of my original question )

Comment: Bloch waves are states of the form $\psi(x)=e^{ikx}u(x)$ with $u(x)$ a periodic function. Here $k$ determines in which direction the wavefunction moves. It is called crystal momentum because it is not the same as regular momentum. The effect of $k$ can be seen in this excellent applet http://www.falstad.com/qm1dcrystal/. So to answer your question the size of $\phi$ roughly corresponds to momentum (but only very roughly).

Comment: If you just took $\lambda=1$ you would be left with just the $k=0$ state, since $u(x)$ _is_ exactly periodic.

Answer (score 0):

The translation operator is the unitary $T_L = e^{i\hat pL}$. Since $V$ is translation-invariant, the Hamiltonian commutes with $p$ and therefore, for any energy eigenvector $\psi$ we have

$$T_L\psi = e^{ipL}\psi$$